# Link to yammer group in embedded web part using Title URL changes "/#/" with "/%23/"

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, yammer, embedded

We have embedded a yammer group on a SharePoint Online page. Everything works fine.

But I want to add a link to that group, so users could open yammer group directly in new window. I put url in a Script Editor Web Part's Title URL field. Web Part Title is active, but url is changed.

Instead of `https://www.yammer.com/company.com/#/threads/company?type=general`

It becomes: `https://www.yammer.com/company.com/%23/threads/company?type=general`

Of course this link is not working and go to page not found.

Is there an another way to insert correct URL and show it as WebPart Title? 
Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

In Web Part I disabled the Title (Chrome Type - None). And in code snippet before yammer's script I have added Title with correct link using css class from webpart, like:

```
<h2 style="text-align:justify;" class="ms-webpart-titleText"><a href="https://www.yammer.com/company.com/#/threads/company?type=general" target="_blank"><nobr><span>Yammer Discussion Forum</span></nobr></a></h2>
```